# VS 2015: Selenium webdriver reference isn't found

Tags: selenium, webdriver, c#, visualstudio

I just started with Selenium and C# and came across this problem at very beginning. I've installed nuget webdriver package in project WebdriverTest, then created Unit test project in which I add reference to WebdriverTest project.
But the unit test doesn't recognize the selenium webdriver reference in WebdriverTest project at all.

[image: VSReference]

Comment: This is actually a basic coding question. If you want to use WebDriver in your UnitTest Project, you must have the WebDriver reference in your UnitTest project, not just the other project in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The project reference for "WebdirverTest" in the UnitTest project's references does not include any libraries that are in "WebdirverTest", it only includes references to classes within that project. You must add the library to *both* projects. As @ChathuD said, the Nuget Package Manager is a useful tool for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Try Nuget manager or use Package Manager Console with below command:
Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 2.53.1